# need to postpone watch on input model till mouse leave or tab enter in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I am using  ag-grid with cell renderer as input box, as I am facing problem to fire event on ng-blur in ag-grid, I have tried with $watch on ng-model of the input box. Now the event is firing whenever I made changes to text input box. But the problem I am facing here is, let say if I need to enter 35 in the text box, the `computeStatus` function inside the watch is getting triggered for each number I have entered. i.e, after entering 3 the `computeStatus` function triggers and then if I enter 5 (to complete 35) then again `computeStatus`  function triggers. Is there any way to postpone this triggering of `computeStatus`, till I leave the input box either through mouse leave or tab event. I spend lot of time to use ng-blur but the event is not at all triggering so finally I have used this approach but facing the reported problem. Any solution ...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="assHrs" > 

$scope.$watch('assHrs', function(hrs) {
  computeStatus(hrs);        
  }, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the 1.3.x version of Angular, it has a directive called [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) that is used to control when model is updated.

`<input type="text" ng-model="assHrs" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}">`

This will cause model update only when you leave the input.

Comment: I cam across this but not clear how to use it, I have referred ng-docs too. After I changed the value I need call computeStatus function. So, how to do that. I have changed <input type="text" ng-model="assHrs" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" >, now shall I need to write $scope.updateOn = function (){ cal to computeStatus} and remove the above watch I have defined?

Comment: You can use the same watch that you have defined. Or do `ng-change=computeStatus(assHrs)`

Comment: I am using the following ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}"  ng-change="addNewDpt()" for input text box which is working fine only when I click mouse outside the text box, after changing the value in text box. I want the same to happen even clicking TAB or ENTER key, how can I do it? You can find my post on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541411/need-to-extend-ng-model-options-to-work-with-enter-and-tab-key-events-in-angualr

Comment: I believe TAB and ENTER key should have safe effect

Comment: Sorry I did not follow you clearly, what do you mean by safe effect?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, i mean "same effect"

Comment: No that is happening only if I click my mouse outside after entering the text the change function is triggering up. If click enter or Tab after entering the text into the input box, the change function is not getting triggered. For I now I have ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}", shall I need to add anything else to updateOn in mg-model-options, other than blur?